# (Verilog) Testbench Wait

Tags: time, verilog, wait, test-bench

I am having problems with creating a testbench for my adders. When I start the testbench it will assign the initial start time as `t1` and input `a` and `b` and when `cout` is a 1 it will set the final time to `t2`. Finally the delay is the subtraction of `t2` and `t1`.

The problem is mostly syntax errors.

This is my code so far:

```
parameter N = 16;
parameter A = 0;

reg[N-1:0] a, b;
wire[N-1:0] sum;
reg cin;
wire cout;

arith_unit #(.ADDER_TYPE(A), .WIDTH(N)) tb (.a(a),.b(b),.cin(cin),.sum(sum),.cout(cout));
initial begin
a = 0;
b = 0;
cin = 0;
#50;


$time(t1);

a = 16'b0010110110100010;
b = 16'b1011111101100111; 
cin = 1'b0;

wait (if (cout == 1)) $time(t2); <-------sytax error here

int delay = t2 - t1; <-------sytax error here

$display ("%d", delay);
end
endmodule
```

Thank you for the help.

Comment: use  `wait(count == 1)`; the second error most likely is due to the first one.

Answer (score 0):

- `wait (if (cout == 1))` should be `wait (cout == 1)`.
- `int` doesn't exist as a variable type in Verilog (it does in
  SystemVerilog). I think you want `integer` or `time`. Also note that a variable can not be created simply
  anywhere. In Verilog, it needs to declared with your `reg` and `wire`
  declarations.
- `$time` doesn't take arguments. Use `t1 = $time;`
- `t1` and `t2` are not declared. Perhaps `integer` or `time`.

Unless you have some delay inside `arith_unit` the delay will be 0. If there is delay, you may want to double check that `cout` is glitch free as `wait` cannot distinguish between glitches and stable signals.